# How to implement ctrl+f in a javafx text area

Tags: javafx

I've got a big multi line TextArea in javaFX. Is there a good way to implement ctrl-f as a find command? Basically to highlight the searched-for text.

I know how to listen for a keystroke, but how do I A) Highlight the text and B) Scroll to the part of the TextArea that has the text?

Comment: Aren't `TextField`s single-line by definition? What are you actually asking here: how to know when ctrl-f is pressed? Or how to do the highlighting? Or something else?

Comment: Oh that's my bad. I meant TextArea. And yeah so I'd need to A) Listen for ctrl+f to get hit, then highlight the text, and then scroll to the part of the text area the text can be found in. It's moreso the last two pieces I need help with. I'll amend my question.

Comment: Probably right now your question is too broad. If you could create a simple [MCVE] showing what you have done and where you are stuck, you might be more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented something similar.  Assuming you can listen for the CTRL + F which provide the user something to search for, you could do a method similar to this which would look for it.

```
private void findAndSelectString(String lookingFor)
{
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + lookingFor + "\\b");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input.getText()); //Where input is a TextInput class
    boolean found = matcher.find(0);
    if(found){
        input.selectRange(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
    }
}
```

You might want to do this recursively which means you might want to store the last position so you can keep looking....

Comment: Thanks for this. How did you end up implementing the text entry? Did you pop up a search field or did you just capture text entered shortly after the ctrl-f?

Comment: Actually this was pulled from a Spell Check function  I wrote.  Basically a person would hit spell check and it would search the text input to look for errors and would go one by one through them.